# Java enum type name reflection

Tags: java, reflection, enums

I want to retrieve the name of the enum type from within the enum type itself:

```
enum Mammals {
    DOG(new Dog()),
    CAT(new Cat());

    public String alias;

    Mammals(AncestorOfDogAndCat a){
        this.alias=this.getClass().getName().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(alias);
    }
}
```

When I instance them I get

```
Main$mammals
Main$mammals
```

but I want

```
dog
cat
```

Comment: you didn't pass parameter on constructor but i can see each enum constant has values. why?

Comment: @atiqkhaled sorry, I stripped some unnecessary code but left some garbage

Comment: I don't understand why you need to pass the Dog instance if you are not using nor storing it. There are several answers already relying on the `name()` method but if you need the instance coudn't you simply call to its `toString` method? That would make the print dependant to the dog/cat instance instead of the enum type name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `name()` method on an enum constant to get the name of the enum constant:

```
enum Mammals {
    DOG(),
    CAT();

    public String alias;

    Mammals() {
        this.alias = name().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(alias);
    }
}
```

The `name()` method is something that is automatically added by the compiler on `enum` types.

Comment: From [the documentation for `name`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name--): "**Most programmers should use the toString() method in preference to this one, as the toString method may return a more user-friendly name.** This method is designed primarily for use in specialized situations where correctness depends on getting the exact name, which will not vary from release to release."

Comment: @Michael which means the `name()` method is exactly what you should use if your program depends on it; what `toString()` returns is more intended for humans to read.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use reflection. It's not robust enough. Provide a method which provides this information.

```
interface Animal
{
    String getName();
}

class Dog implements Animal
{
    public String getName()
    {
        return "dog";
    }
}

enum Mammals {
    DOG(new Dog()),
    CAT(new Cat());

    public String alias;

    Mammals (Animal animal) {
        this.alias = animal.getName();
        System.out.println(alias);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate why reflection isn't robust?

Comment: You're creating a link between the class name to run-time behaviour. Bad idea. What if you someone comes along later and refactors the `Dog` class and changes the name to `Canine`? Seems like a reasonable change - it will compile fine. Only days, weeks, months later will you realise you've broken something.

Comment: @Michael although I accept your concerns about reflection, if you are only looking for the name you can use the `name` method for enums instead of adding a new parameter with a "custom" string value. I mean, with your same argument, if someone refactors the class the enum is still showing the "dog" value and it should now be "canine"

Comment: @CristianRamon-Cortes No good programmer would reasonably expect refactoring the class name to Canine to change run-time behaviour to output 'Canine'.

Comment: @Michael we could discuss it further but I would expect something more like the solution you have edited now. I mean, if someone refactors the dog class he will refactor the `getName` or the `toString` method conveniently.

Comment: Changing a class name affects binary compatibility and serialization so it's not reasonable to expect that changing a class name would not break anything.

Comment: @Radiodef Yes, that's worth considering but I never said that.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Mammals {
    DOG(new Dog()),
    CAT(new Cat());

    public String alias;

    Mammals(DogOrCat value){
        this.alias=name().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(alias);
    }
}
```

or use `toString()`, which by default is implemented using `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.getClass()` will return the name of the class itself, which is the enum Mammals here. Instead take in a parameter and use getClass on the parameter for your alias.

```
enum Mammals {
DOG(new Dog()),
CAT(new Cat());

public String alias;

  Mammals(Animal an){
      this.alias=an.getClass().getName().toLowerCase();
      System.out.println(alias);
  }
}
```

where Dog and Cat extend Animal.